# double.TryParse buggy?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

It seems like my VS2010 is acting weird (or may be its just me) !

What is so invalid in the following argument?

[image]

Am I the only person getting this error ?

Comment: `TryParse` returns `bool`, not `double`.

Comment: 0d is not a double variable

Comment: Thats a Zero my friend with a 'd' for double

Comment: @deb - You can't use the constant `0d`, you need to pass a variable. `TryParse` returns a bool and the `out` parameter fills the variable you passed in with the parsed double.

Comment: @CuongLe it's not `Od`, it's `0d`, so it's already defined, but still invalid

Comment: If you describe for me what part of the documentation was unclear I can pass that along to the MSDN documentation manager.

Comment: Just so you know, you'd get much less downvotes if you first assumed it was your mistake and not a bug in Visual Studio. There may be some sneaky bugs deep down in VS but 99-100% of the time it will be your own fault.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've misunderstood what `TryParse` does. If you're sure `lati.Text` is a valid double, use `double.Parse(lati.Text)`. It takes a string and returns a double. Your getter would look like:

```
get { return double.Parse(lat1.Text); }
```

in this case if `lat1.Text` is not a valid double it would throw an exception and break. If this is not the behaviour you want you should use `double.TryParse` which gives back a bool (true if it parsed the text successfully, false if not). The second parameter in `TryParse` has to be a holder variable which - after `TryParse` has finished - will hold the parsed value you were after. Using this approach your code would look like this:

```
get
{
    double lat;
    if (double.TryParse(lat1.Text, out lat))
        return lat;
    else
    {
        // This line is reached if lat1.Text is not a valid double.
        // You decide what's best to do here
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass an actual double to store the result.
The method TryParse declare the second parameter as an `out double`, meaning that it intends to store something there.

```
get
{
    double d;
    double.TryParse(lat1.Text, out d);
    return d;
}
```

It is ironic that this behaviour could be considered 'buggy'.
In the ancient days of bare naked C an error like that could wipe out your hard disk.

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign a `const double` to an `out`-parameter. Give it a `double`-variable!

```
string s = "1.23";
double d = 0.0;
double.TryParse(s, out d);
```

Comment: No, give it a double *variable*.

Comment: Everything in .NET is treated as an object, even the "small" built-in types.

Comment: I am aware of that. An *object* is not a *variable*. A variable is a storage location which can store a value; if the variable is of value type then the object stored in the variable is an instance of value type. If the variable is of reference type then the value stored in the variable is a reference to an object, or null.  But under no circumstances is a *variable* the same thing as an *object*. The argument passed to a method that takes an *out* parameter must be a *variable*.

Comment: Also, note that it is unnecessary to initialize `d` to zero; methods which take `out` parameters are required to initialize the variable for you.

Answer (score 3):

your getter should be somthing like this

```
get {
 double result;
 if(!double.TryParse(lati.Text, out result))
    throw new Exception("your message");
 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in TryParse needs to be a variable.  You are passing in a constant, 0.

Comment: You forget the return type. `TryParse` returns a `bool`, but he wants to return a `double`